# Left align content inside a Tailwinds centered flex column

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a centered column where I'd like to align some of the content inside this column to the left:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">

  <!-- I would like all elements to be left aligned in this div -->
  <div class="items-start justify-start">
    <h1>Tailwind Elements</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How can I left align content in a flex column that is centered? I can not seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set width for the inner div? I set the width and used `text-left` and it seems to work

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">

  <!-- I would like all elements to be left aligned in this div -->
  <div class="w-[400px] text-left bg-red-500">
    <h1>Tailwind Elements</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Edit: you don't even have to use `text-left` as setting the width automatically sets all the items to be left aligned